# Google Cloud Endpoints get-client-lib error: Object type K not supported

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm attempting to compile a Google Cloud Endpoints project in Java, but I'm getting the following error:

> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Object type K not supported.

I don't have any public methods in any of my API classes that take in or return a generic type (`K` or otherwise), nor any class specifically named `K`. My body types should all be entity types by the documentation's definitions.

The biggest change I've made recently is that I moved my model (which defines the entity types) to a separate project and I'm including those classes as a JAR dependency.

I'm on the App Engine SDK version 1.9.51 (recently upgraded to this), though using previous versions doesn't seem to change anything. I'm using Gradle with the [gradle-appengine-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) (eventually planning to migrate to the newer [app-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin)).

Any thoughts on why this is happening, and what steps I might take to resolve?

**EDIT:**

I seem to have isolated the problem, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

I have a list method in my API that returns an object containing a list of other objects. Something like:

```
public class ListWrapper() implements Serializable {

    private List<Object> list;

    public List<Object> getList() { return list; }

    public void setList(List<Object> list) { this.list = list; }

}
```

It seems to be this List type which is suddenly the problem. If I remove it from the class, it works fine. If I edit the method to return something else, it works fine. But, in a previous version of the code, this `LsitWrapper` object existed and was returned exactly as it is and worked fine. What has changed? (Reverting back to earlier versions of the App Engine SDK doesn't seem to help.)

Comment: Did this ever actually work? I would suggest that there's not much point in using this class either. It will make it so that Endpoints doesn't know the schema for anything you return since you use `List<Object>`.

Comment: It used to work, hence my confusion; the list isn't the only thing in the wrapper, I use it to relay pagination data, including more than `CollectionResponse` offers, namely a count of total results (beyond the returned page). Can/should I be extending `CollectionResponse` in order to add that information?

Comment: Endpoints Frameworks v1 doesn't do the greatest job with generics. v2 does a bit better. If you are wanting to extend `CollectionResponse`, you don't necessarily need to inherit the class, but you should make your `ListWrapper` generic. Can you try generating your client lib using `endpoints.sh` from the SDK?

Comment: Running it from `endpoints.cmd` produces the same error.

Comment: Does reversing the refactor make a difference?

Comment: When I revert back to my pre-refactor branch, it works perfectly and lets me use my wrapper.

Comment: This is interesting. Do you have time to produce a minimal project that has the same issue?

Comment: I don't really have time to do so, but I did find something new: I was refactoring to return an extension of `CollectionResponse` instead of my wrapper, and some of my endpoint classes would work fine, and others wouldn't.

Eventually I was able to narrow it down to a single property that was in an object that all of my returning objects extended. That property was not a valid JavaBean/entity type. If the extending object had a getter for it (marked as ignored), it worked. If there was no getter, it failed with the above message.

Comment: Is the property intended to be exposed? Furthermore, what is the type of the property?